# Master of Many Forms Tripper Questions

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I am making a gestalt character and was dead set on basing it off of a tripper I absolutely loved playing awhile back.  The DM is fairly open to any official source except BoED, BoVD, Dragon Mag, or any psionics.  The last bit is what tripped (no pun intended) me up.  The original build used psy warrior to get expansion for the ability to go large.

I came up with the idea of going master of many forms to get the Improved wild shape large and humanoid so I could just shape into a large version of myself.

My questions are:

1. Would this work?
2. How would stats be affected when I shape (I assume it would just be the standard medium to large adj, but I'm not sure)?
3. Is there a better option out there (I know this plan comes with the issue with gear melding, I have plans for that as well)?

I have the build planned out to level 12 as of right now and would be more than willing to share if asked, but I don't think those details are relevant to the questions right now.

Answer (score 2):

Master of many forms can definitely get larger, but you have to turn into something that is Large or whatever—you can’t turn into “creature *x* except Large.” And that’s not even getting into the issue of whether or not a master of many forms can take on the form of a specific individual, i.e. you, or what happens when and if you do.

As for what stats you do or don’t get, improved wild shape world like wild shape which works like [alternate form](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#alternateForm). So those are the rules you would work from.

Among those rules is that fact that you keep your feats, so you could always just take tripping feats, and then wild shape into something big and strong to trip with. Eliminates the concern for your items melding into your body, and there are some great options.

If you want to stay as yourself, a cleric could run *righteous might* with Divine Metamagic (Persist Spell). You would probably also want to persist *divine power*, so this approach requires quite a bit of turn undead, but would be very strong—plus you could back up your tripping with the incredible power of cleric spellcasting. This would probably be strongest approach.

At 17th, *shapechange* kind of makes master of many forms obsolete—at that point, druid, wizard, or cleric with the right domain is best. Of course, at that point, tripping won’t matter anyway.

Comment: @Deicidal Weapon-using forms are unusual; most masters of many forms go with natural attacks. For weapons, the cleric is probably the much-better choice. Pounce will be hard to find, too, since that’s usually on cats—a barbarian dip with the _Complete Champion_ lion spiritual totem is recommended so you just have pounce yourself. As for at-will changes, _Complete Warrior_’s warshaper allows that, but requires 5 levels to get it. _Shapechange_ does too, but you already said that was out. Otherwise, that’s pretty tough to get.

Comment: Can master of many forms utilize creature progression to be a larger size based on its hd?

Comment: @WannabeWarlock Certainly not. Those rules exist *only* for DMs who want to advance a creature to make it a little tougher than its default; they’re part of that advancement process, not an inherent feature of having *x* HD. Same reason animal companions don’t get them. (And in any event, it doesn’t matter as playable races don’t have those rules to begin with, and Deicidal is trying to turn into “*myself* except Large,” which their PC never would become through advancement anyway.)

Comment: @Deicidal Oh, but I should mention—if what you want is some form of shapechanging that allows you to change your choices on the fly, you can totally ask that question. We know *shapechange* and a warshaper’s multimorph are two ways to get it; there may be more.